# React Native - Redux combineReducers not working

Tags: react-native, redux

I try to save three values in redux for counters. This is my file with the combineReducers:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

const SET_FREUNDE = 'SET_FREUNDE';
const SET_CHATS = 'SET_CHATS';
const SET_VOTES = 'SET_VOTES';

export function setFreunde(value) {
  return {
    type: SET_FREUNDE,
    value,
  }
}

export function setChats(value) {
  return {
    type: SET_CHATS,
    value,
  }
}

export function setVotes(value) {
  return {
    type: SET_VOTES,
    value,
  }
}

const defaults = [
  {
    countervotes: 1,
    counterchats: 1,
    counterfreunde: 1
  }
];


function counter(state=defaults, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_FREUNDE:
      return [
        ...state,
        {
          ...state.counterfreunde = action.value
        }
      ];
      case SET_CHATS:
        return [
          ...state,
          {
            ...state.counterchats = action.value
          }
        ];
        case SET_VOTES:
          return [
            ...state,
            {
              ...state.countervotes = action.value
            }
          ];
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const counters = combineReducers({
  counter
});

export default counters;
```

In my App.tsx I create the store and want to get the values:

```
import { Provider, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { createStore} from "redux";
import counters from './src/redux/counter';

const store = createStore(counters);

const AppStack = () => {
    const counterfreunde = useSelector((state)=>state.counterfreunde);
    const counterchats = useSelector((state)=>state.counterchats);
    const countervotes = useSelector((state)=>state.countervotes);
    return(
      ...
    )
   }

const App = () => {

  ...
    return(
        <Provider store={store} >
          <AppStack/>
        </Provider>
    );
  
}

export default App;
```

But counterfreunde, ... are undefined. If I set the values directly in the store like this:

```
const store = createStore(() => ({
  counterfreunde: 1,
  counterchats: 1,
  counterfreunde: 1
}));
```

all works fine. I think the problem is with the definition of the combineReducer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `combineReducers`, you provide it with a "Reducers Map Object" that maps the property names of the state to reducer that controls that property.

```
const counters = combineReducers({
  counter
});
```

Calling `combineReducers` like above says that your root state has a property `counter` which is controlled by your `counter` reducer.

This is fine in isolation, but it changes your selectors because the properties like `counterfreunde` are not properties of the top-level state, they are properties of `state.counter`.  So your selectors would need to be like this:

```
const counterfreunde = useSelector((state) => state.counter.counterfreunde);
```

If `counter` is the only reducer that you have then you don't need to use `combineReducers`.  You can keep your selectors the same as they are now by providing your `counter` reducer as the reducer for the root state.

```
function counter(state=defaults, action) {
  ...
}

// remove the combineReducers

export default counter;
```

```
const store = createStore(counter);
```

Comment: thank you that has already brought me further. So now I get the values. But now I can not change them. I try it as follows:
import { setChats, setFreunde, setVotes } from '../redux/counter';

`const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => ({
  setFreunde: () => {
    const { value } = ownProps

    dispatch(setFreunde(value))
  },
  setChats: () => {
    const { value } = ownProps
    dispatch(setChats(value))
  },
  setVotes: () => {
    const { value } = ownProps
    dispatch(setVotes(value))
  }
})`
but if i call it nothing changes:
`() => setFreunde(2)`

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the issue is in your combineReducers invocation. Attached is a working, nested reducer formulated by combining other reducers.

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import {
  RESETPLAN,
  SELECTEDPLAN,
  selectPlanActionType,
} from './selectedPlan/types';
import { planType } from './plans/types';

import { PROTECTEDPLANS, plansActionType, plansType } from './plans/types';

const defaultSelectedState: planType = {};
const defaultPlanState: plansType = {
  list: [],
};

function plansReducer(
  state: plansType = defaultPlanState,
  action: plansActionType
): plansType {
  switch (action.type) {
    case PROTECTEDPLANS: {
      return {
        ...state,
        ...action.payload,
      };
    }

    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}

function selectedReducer(
  state: planType = defaultSelectedState,
  action: selectPlanActionType
): planType {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SELECTEDPLAN: {
      return {
        ...state,
        ...action.payload,
      };
    }

    case RESETPLAN: {
      return defaultSelectedState;
    }

    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}

export default combineReducers({
  myPlans: plansReducer,
  selected: selectedReducer,
});
```

Comment: Could you please tell me what exactly  is wrong?

Comment: I changed it to this:
`const defaults =
  {
    countervotes: 1,
    counterchats: 1,
    counterfreunde: 1
  };


function counter(state=defaults, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_FREUNDE: {
      return {...state,counterfreunde: action.value}
    }
      case SET_CHATS: {
        return {...state,counterchats: action.value}
      }
        case SET_VOTES: {
          return {...state,countervotes: action.value}
        }
    default:{
      return state;
    }
  }
}

export default counter;`

Comment: and now i get the values. But i cant set the value with this:
`import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { setChats, setFreunde, setVotes } from '../redux/counter';

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => ({
  setFreunde: () => {
    const { value } = ownProps

    dispatch(setFreunde(value))
  },
  setChats: () => {
    const { value } = ownProps
    dispatch(setChats(value))
  },
  setVotes: () => {
    const { value } = ownProps
    dispatch(setVotes(value))
  }
})` and `<Button onPress={() => setFreunde(2)} />`
what is the mistake?